# How do you check if 153 is a Narcissistic number using python?

Tags: python

I have this question about checking if 153 is a [Narcissistic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) and I don't know where to start, please help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number

Answer (score 3):

a simple function to solve it

```
def check_is_narcis_number(your_number):
    your_numbers = str(your_number)
    power = len(your_numbers)
    your_sum = 0
    for number in your_numbers:
        your_sum += pow(int(number), power)
    if your_sum == your_number:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use the definition of a Narcissistic number. The definition is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number). So for 153 (3 digits) its. 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153. So yes 153 is a Narcissistic number.

In python you need to determine the number of digits. The just follow the definition as I showed you earlier.  You can read the number in as a string and then use len(number) to get the number of digits.

Then you can use int(number[0]) to convert the string to an integer. so for each digit you calculate int(num[0])**len(number).. Repeat this for the 2nd digit and the 3rd digit and add all 3 together. 
If total equals 153 then its a Narcissistic number.

Just put this in a code and thats your answer.